# Flutter: Controlling the scroll of 2 different controllers

Tags: flutter, controller

So, I have two different scroll widgets, viz., TextField and ListView (ListView.builder) attached with two different scroll controllers, viz,. _textEditingController and _scrollController.

The basic concept here is to make a ruled-line like structure and a textfield on top of it using Stack and scrollable widgets. How do I move one controller with the motion/scroll action of the other ?

```
Stack(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height:
          ((lines * 15) < MediaQuery.of(context).size.height)
              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
              : (lines * 15),
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
          child: Divider(
            color: Colors.black,
            height: 30,
            thickness: 1.5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10)
          .copyWith(top: 5),
      child: TextField(
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontFamily: "WorkSans",
          fontSize: 26,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
          height: 1.55,
        ),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        controller: _textEditingController,
        maxLines: lines,
        onChanged: (value) {
          /* This function adds another line if I am at the end
          of the text field, thus increasing the ListView's height */
          final selection = _textEditingController.selection;
          if (isAtLastLine(selection)) {
            setState(() {
              lines++;
            });
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use physics in ListView.builder and shrinkWrap for solving height issues

```
ListView.builder(
     shrinkWrap: true,
     physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
     itemCount: recommendedJobsList.length,
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     return your code here;
});
```

Comment: Since I want the dividers to spawn endlessly, i.e., without the itemCount param, I am not sure if I can solve height issues. Also, I need the ListView to scroll along with the textfield, so NeverScrollabeScrollPhysics would deny my requirement, I guess.

Comment: if you are using singlechildscrollview then NeverScrollableScrollPhysics wouldn't deny your requirement if not then it will. Listview is scrolalong with your textfield just this once.